# Missing GL Extension

Tags: opengl, glew

my code finally compiles fine on my arm cluster.

now i want to run it.
it does not run on the arm itself, as there is no screen attached

```
1 OpenCL Platforms found
Platform 0: (EMBEDDED_PROFILE OpenCL 1.1 ) Vivante Corporation Vivante OpenCL Platform
1 OpenCL devices found for this platform
Device 0: Vivante Corporation Vivante OpenCL Device
Initializing GLUT...
freeglut (./prognonmpi): failed to open display ''
```

when I access the cluster with ssh -Y name i get the following erro message

```
1 OpenCL Platforms found
Platform 0: (EMBEDDED_PROFILE OpenCL 1.1 ) Vivante Corporation Vivante OpenCL Platform
1 OpenCL devices found for this platform
Device 0: Vivante Corporation Vivante OpenCL Device
Initializing GLUT...
init 160 x 100
Loading extensions: Missing GL version
Error: failed to get minimal extensions for demo
This sample requires:
OpenGL version 1.5
GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
```

glxinfo glxgears and so on are running fine and show on my screen, when run on the cluster
which package is missing to get the program running?

Comment: `Missing GL version` happens, if you call `gl*` functions before initializing opengl context. Can it be the case?

Comment: other gl* functions are working fine

Comment: If you look at the source code for GLEW, there is one condition under which it returns `GLEW_ERROR_NO_GL_VERSION`. It queries the string: `GL_VERSION` and then if there is no dot (.) in the string, that is the error it gives. Technically the error is caused by a bad version string, but the most common cause of a bad version string is having no GL context when you call `glewInit (...)`. You should query the strings yourself just to see what's going on.

Comment: when you ssh into another machine with X11 forwarding, glX will per default be forwarded also via indriect rendering, meaning that you end up using your _local_ GL implementation, not the one on the remote machine.

Comment: the thing is the code works fine on my local machine, but does not on the remote ARM machine.

however every time i am switching between local an remote machine i compile the code again.

so on my laptop the code runs fine, but not on the remote ARM